# Flutter - How to save a chart as image in device or send to server?

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I need to make a chart in Flutter with both line graph and point graph in one. I found that [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) library allows 'combo' charts. But I couldn't find a way to save the chart as image in device or send to server. Has anyone faced this issue? I am also open to other libraries if they can perform both of these tasks of creating a combined graph and saving as image. Thank you!

Comment: Use the screenshot package https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

Answer (score 1):

get the render object of the widget with its global key

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
```

convert the render object to Image class

```
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
```

get the byteData

```
ByteData byteData =await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png)
```

get the Uints, this is the image you want to process save to disk or send it over to server

```
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Comment: Thank you. will try and let you know!